# failed to create polling location service android

Tags: android, location, looper

I am trying to create a polling service for location which starts for updates for location and waits 2 mins 
and then removes the updates

when i try to send location using my emulator it seems my locationlistener doesn't recieve one.

is it because i didn't implement a handler for the looper I created in the thread?

or because my thread sleeps so i don't receive any location

```
package android.co.in;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class customThread extends Thread {

boolean stop;
boolean run;
customThread()
{   
    BounceLogger.logIt(this, "Constructor()");
    stop=false;
    run=true;
}
@Override
public void run()
{
  Looper.prepare();
  BounceLogger.logIt(this, "run()");
  while(!stop)
  {
      while(run)
      {
        updateThread(); 
      }

      try 
      {
          wait();
      } 
      catch (InterruptedException e) 
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
  Looper.loop();
}   

//derived class should overide this function
public void updateThread()
{


}


public void runThread()
{  
  start();
}

public void stopThread()
{
    stop=true;
}

public void pauseThread()
{
    run=false;
    BounceLogger.logIt(this,"calling wait on worker thread");
}

public void resumeThread()
{
    BounceLogger.logIt(this,"calling notify on worker thread");
    run=true;
    notify();       
}


}

//responsible for all location related queries
public class UserLocationManager extends customThread{

boolean locationFound;

LocationSelector locationSelector;

UserLocationManager(BuddiesAroundActivity activity)
{
    super();
    locationFound=false;
    locationSelector=LocationSelector.getLocationSelector(activity);
}

Location GetUserLocation()
{
    queryUserLocation();
    return locationSelector.getLastKnownLocation();
}

@Override
public void updateThread()
{
    locationSelector.startListening();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(200000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    locationSelector.stopListening();
}

void queryUserLocation()
{       
    runThread();    
}


}

package android.co.in;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LocationSelector 
{

private static LocationSelector locationSelector=null;
private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
Location lastKnownLocation;

LocationSelector()
{
    Intialize();
}

LocationSelector(BuddiesAroundActivity activity)
{
    Intialize();
    locationManager=
       (LocationManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

static LocationSelector getLocationSelector(BuddiesAroundActivity activity)
{
    if(locationSelector==null)
        locationSelector = new LocationSelector(activity);

    return locationSelector;    
}

void startListening()
{
    if(locationManager!=null)
    {
        BounceLogger.logIt(this, "started listening on location updates");

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,100,     locationListener);
              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,100, locationListener);
    }
}

public void stopListening()
{
    BounceLogger.logIt(this, "stopped listening on location updates");
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}


private void Intialize() 
{
    lastKnownLocation=null;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    locationListener=new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location current) 
        {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location     provider.
            BounceLogger.logIt(this,"recived a location"+current.getLatitude()+":"+current.getLongitude());
            if(lastKnownLocation==null)
            {
                lastKnownLocation=current;
            }
            getBestLocation(lastKnownLocation,current);

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

      };

}

private float getDistanceBetweenLocations(Location a,Location b)
{
    float distance =a.distanceTo(b);     
    return distance;     
}

private double getAngleBetweenLocations(Location origin,Location destination)
{
     double angle=0.0f;
     double longDiff;
     double latDiff;

     longDiff=destination.getLongitude()-origin.getLongitude();
     latDiff=destination.getLatitude()-origin.getLatitude();

     angle=Math.atan2(longDiff,latDiff);         
     return angle; 
 }

Location getLastKnownLocation()
{
    return lastKnownLocation;
}

Location getBestLocation(Location old,Location current)
{
    if(old ==null)
        return current;

    //check time
    long timeDelta = current.getTime() - old.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    int useCurrentLocationByTime=0;
    if(isSignificantlyNewer)
    {
        useCurrentLocationByTime++;
    }

    //check for accuracy
    int useCurrentLocationByAccuracy=0;
    if(old.getAccuracy() < current.getAccuracy())
    {
        useCurrentLocationByAccuracy++;
    }

    //check for provider this is blunt but u might want give priority to providers and then decide
    int useCurrentLocationByProvider=0;
    if(old.getProvider().equals(current.getProvider()))
    {
        useCurrentLocationByProvider++;
    }

    int points=useCurrentLocationByTime+useCurrentLocationByAccuracy+useCurrentLocationByProvider;

    if(points > 1.5)
    {
        return current;     
    }

    return old;     
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your updateThread you start the request for Location and then you put the thread tp sleep for 200 seconds, which makes it impossible to receive new locations. As soon as the thread awake, you remove the Location updates request.

You need to redesign your code, in a way that Location Listner is run in a different thread, or even better, you use a handler.post() method to run a runnable 200 seconds later that would stop location listener and would avoid using threads for that.

--EDITED--

you sould do something like:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
startLocationListener(); //in this method you only add the listener for onLocationsChange(). No threads needed.
handler.postDelayed(rStopLocationListener, 200000); //the runnable rStopLocationListener will run in 200 seconds

//define rStopLocationListener
private Runnable rStopLocationListener = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
          stopLocationListener(); //in this method you only remove the listener for onLocationsChange(). No threads needed.
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for u r response. I will implement it through handle that should be better approach :)

Comment: yes,Thanks for u r offer!!!. please see if this implementation has any problem :)

Answer (score 0):

package android.co.in;

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class customThread extends Thread {

boolean stop;
boolean run;
customThread()
{   
    BounceLogger.logIt(this, "Constructor()");
    stop=false;
    run=true;
}
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
  //Looper.prepare();
  BounceLogger.logIt(this, "run()");
  while(!stop)
  {
      while(run)
      {
        updateThread(); 
      }

      try 
      {
          wait();
      } 
      catch (InterruptedException e) 
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
  //Looper.loop();
    }   

    //derived class should overide this function
   public void updateThread()
  {


  }


  public void runThread()
  {  
  start();
  }

  public void stopThread()
{
    stop=true;
}

  public void pauseThread()
{
    run=false;
    BounceLogger.logIt(this,"calling wait on worker thread");
}

  public void resumeThread()
{
    BounceLogger.logIt(this,"calling notify on worker thread");
    run=true;
    notify();       
}


   }

  class customLooperThread extends Thread {

boolean stop;
boolean run;
customLooperThread()
{   
    BounceLogger.logIt(this, "Constructor()");
    stop=false;
    run=true;
}
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
  Looper.prepare();
  BounceLogger.logIt(this, "run()");
  while(!stop)
  {
      while(run)
      {
        updateThread(); 
      }

      try 
      {
          wait();
      } 
      catch (InterruptedException e) 
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
  Looper.loop();
  } 

   //derived class should overide this function
  public void updateThread()
  {


  }


 public void runThread()
 {  
  start();
 }

 public void stopThread()
{
    stop=true;
}

 public void pauseThread()
{
    run=false;
    BounceLogger.logIt(this,"calling wait on worker thread");
}

  public void resumeThread()
{
    BounceLogger.logIt(this,"calling notify on worker thread");
    run=true;
    notify();       
}


   }




   //responsible for all location related queries
   public class UserLocationManager extends customLooperThread{

boolean locationFound;

LocationSelector locationSelector;
Handler h;

UserLocationManager(BuddiesAroundActivity activity,Handler uiHandler)
{
    super();
    locationFound=false;
    locationSelector=LocationSelector.getLocationSelector(activity);

}

Location GetUserLocation()
{
    queryUserLocation();
    return locationSelector.getLastKnownLocation();
}

@Override
public void updateThread() 
{
    locationSelector.startListening();
    h= new Handler();
    h.postAtTime(locationSelector, 20000);
    try {
        sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    locationSelector.stopListening();
}

void queryUserLocation()
{       
    runThread();    
}


   }



   public class LocationSelector extends customThread
   {

private static LocationSelector locationSelector=null;
private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
Location lastKnownLocation;

LocationSelector()
{
    Intialize();
}

LocationSelector(BuddiesAroundActivity activity)
{
    Intialize();
    locationManager= 
                 (LocationManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

static LocationSelector getLocationSelector(BuddiesAroundActivity activity)
{
    if(locationSelector==null)
        locationSelector = new LocationSelector(activity);

    return locationSelector;    
}

void startListening()
{
    if(locationManager!=null)
    {
        BounceLogger.logIt(this, "started listening on location updates");

          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,100,   
          locationListener);

      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,100,                   
      locationListener);
    }
}

public void stopListening()
{
    BounceLogger.logIt(this, "stopped listening on location updates");
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}


@Override
public void updateThread()
{
BounceLogger.logIt(this, "updateThread");
}


private void Intialize() 
{
    lastKnownLocation=null;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    locationListener=new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location current) 
        {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            BounceLogger.logIt(this,"recived a location"+current.getLatitude()+":"+current.getLongitude());
            if(lastKnownLocation==null)
            {
                lastKnownLocation=current;
            }
            getBestLocation(lastKnownLocation,current);

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

      };

}

private float getDistanceBetweenLocations(Location a,Location b)
{
    float distance =a.distanceTo(b);     
    return distance;     
}

private double getAngleBetweenLocations(Location origin,Location destination)
{
     double angle=0.0f;
     double longDiff;
     double latDiff;

     longDiff=destination.getLongitude()-origin.getLongitude();
     latDiff=destination.getLatitude()-origin.getLatitude();

     angle=Math.atan2(longDiff,latDiff);         
     return angle; 
 }

Location getLastKnownLocation()
{
    return lastKnownLocation;
}

Location getBestLocation(Location old,Location current)
{
    if(old ==null)
        return current;

    //check time
    long timeDelta = current.getTime() - old.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    int useCurrentLocationByTime=0;
    if(isSignificantlyNewer)
    {
        useCurrentLocationByTime++;
    }

    //check for accuracy
    int useCurrentLocationByAccuracy=0;
    if(old.getAccuracy() < current.getAccuracy())
    {
        useCurrentLocationByAccuracy++;
    }

    //check for provider this is blunt but u might want give priority to providers and then decide
    int useCurrentLocationByProvider=0;
    if(old.getProvider().equals(current.getProvider()))
    {
        useCurrentLocationByProvider++;
    }

    int points=useCurrentLocationByTime+useCurrentLocationByAccuracy+useCurrentLocationByProvider;

    if(points > 1.5)
    {
        return current;     
    }

    return old;     
}
```

}